# Replacing values in multiple columns

Tags: python, perl, awk

This question has been asked before but mine is quite specific hence I am posting the question.

I have a file which looks like this:

```
chr10 100008748 100010821 2 2 1
chr10 100011459 100012109 2 2 1
chr10 100015496 100016536 2 2 1
chr10 100017921 100018765 2 2 1
chr10 100018985 100019147 2 2 1
chr10 100022808 100027387 2 2 0
chr10 100143625 100144703 2 2 1
chr10 100144824 100146957 2 2 1
chr10 100144941 100146957 2 2 0
chr10 100147064 100148110 2 2 1
```

My task is to replace the 6th column values with a '.' (period) and the 5th column with either +/-. If the value in $5 is 1 then "-" else "+".

I have tried some python and perl scripts along with some awk commands but not much has worked for me.

A pesudocode would be much appreciated, thank you for your time.

**** using AWK ****

```
BEGIN { FS=OFS=' ' } 
> $6 == "1" { $6 == "." }
> $6 == "0" { $6 == "." }
> 1
> ' Illumina_Heart_Gencode_AlignedSJ_cut.bed > test2.bed

awk '{ gsub(".",$6); print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}' Illumina_Heart_Gencode_AlignedSJ_cut.bed > test.bed
```

Tried to find the Perl and Python files but I guess I deleted them.

Comment: Let's have a look at what you've tried

Comment: `If the value in $5 is 1 then "-" else "+".` did mistook `$6` with `$5` here?

Comment: i don't know how it's too broad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Through awk,

```
$ awk '{$6="."; if ($5==1){$5="-"} else $5="+"}1' file
chr10 100008748 100010821 2 + .
chr10 100011459 100012109 2 + .
chr10 100015496 100016536 2 + .
chr10 100017921 100018765 2 + .
chr10 100018985 100019147 2 + .
chr10 100022808 100027387 2 + .
chr10 100143625 100144703 2 + .
chr10 100144824 100146957 2 + .
chr10 100144941 100146957 2 + .
chr10 100147064 100148110 2 + .
```

It replaces 6th column value with a `.` and if the value of column 5 is `1` then it replaces all the characters in  column 5 with `-` else it replaces all the values with `+`

Comment: @AvinashRaj No, nothing wrong with the code, I mis-understood the question. Here is a shorter option `awk '{$6=".";$5=($5==1?"-":"+")}1' file` (but thats just a matter of preference).

Comment: That's an interesting solution. +1.